# List saved as template does not appear under Add an app

Tags: list, list-template

I have Task List in 2010 site. I have save that list as template.
Uploaded that template in SharePoint 2013 site. 
[image]

Now I'm unable to create a new list based on this template.

I have used that [article](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/bd875797-c269-44bd-aeae-0d52870e4d1c/sharepoint-2013-when-saving-list-template-unable-to-create-new-list-from-saved-template?forum=sharepointgeneral) but it not helped that much

Comment: Have you upload list template in list template gallery?
In SharePoint 2010 and SharePoint 2013 task content type change so it may cause problem.
In SharePoint 2010 Content Type Name is Workflow Task and SharePoint 2013 Workflow Task(2013)

Comment: I had a similar issue I ended up creating a new list in SP 2013 using visual studio. And to create a list with workflow task you can use visual studio as creating it using the site will only show you Workflow Task(2013) unlike visual studio.

Comment: Actually I have to migrate list including data.